# How to gain experience on a skill?

Tags: job-search, career-development, job-change

When I look at job postings related to my specialisation, some skills are required but I have no actual experience yet for those (example API testing). I only know the concepts and basics since I self study. What are the ways for me to acquire the experience I need for the skills for which there is no opportunity for me to learn at work?

Comment: Practice makes perfect. NO, practice with knowledge of results makes perfect…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

more than simply practicing at home, find an open source project with needs on the topic, and practice at work on it.

effect number 1 : you learn to test other's APIs in a more realistic context.

effect number 2 : you can actually sell your newly acquired skill, by showing your work in a realistic setup.

Comment: Great detailed answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Practice at home using the internet.